# Fullcalendar, I can't change allDayText

Tags: javascript, internationalization, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the text of "all day" in agendaWeek and agendaDay views.
I have set allDayText property during initialization, but it's ignored.
I noticed that the problem occurs only if i set a specific language; if i set lang='en' it works correctly, instead with other languages does not.

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sapifojevo/edit?js,output

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

FullCalendar [uses undocumented option `allDayHtml`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/v2.7.3/src/agenda/AgendaView.js#L512) for the agenda view, that has higher priority than `allDayText`. Some languages (including Italian) localize it via `allDayHtml` option and your `allDayText` value is ignored in this case.

Comment: Thank you, setting allDayHtml property it works correctly!